# I have add a bounty, then answered myself, no one else answered? what to do?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

Can I receive bounty back to myself, or may be better to give it to anybody who will write something useful on topic, not necessary answering a question?

The question is [link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/117850/google-mobile-usability-says-content-wider-than-screen-even-though-i-cant-rep)

Edit: I have added to answer:

> Since I put a bounty to this question, before answered myself, somebody needed to receive it. Write something useful on topic, and you get it.

I this correct, didn't I broke any site rules?

Comment: According to [what is a bounty](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/bounty): `To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).`  Therefore you may have to double the bounty of 50 points to 100. Would you like for me to remove the bounty and return it to you?

Comment: @dan Yes, please do

Comment: OK, I removed the bounty and it was added back to your account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To close out this discussion question as completed, I'm copying my comments here as an answer:

According to [what is a bounty](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/bounty): `To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).`  Therefore you may have to double the bounty of 50 points to 100.

Since you just added the bounty and raised the issue here right afterwards, there were no other answers, and you provided an acceptable answer yourself and would have to double the bounty...I removed the bounty from your question as you requested. The reputation points were returned back to your account by the system.

Answer (score 4):

As stated on [What is a bounty?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) help center, generally the bounty is non-refundable.

> It is funded by the personal reputation of the user who offers it, and is **non-refundable**.
>
> - **All bounties are paid for up front and non-refundable under any circumstances.**

"Under any circumstances" also includes if the bounty giver doesn't get any satisfying answers.

Also, bounty giver can't get the bounty to their own answer

> (You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.)

---

[dan](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28389/dan) was nice enough to refund your bounty, but make this event as a lesson that bounty usually won't be refunded and will go wasted if there's no new answer (excluding your own answer).